# How to solve iTextSharp error PDF in ASP.NET Core 6?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-core, itext, visual-studio-2022

I create a simple code for generate a pdf file, this is the code

```
        public IActionResult reporte()
        {
            
            Document doc=new Document();
            MemoryStream ms = new MemoryStream();
            PdfWriter writer = PdfWriter.GetInstance(doc, ms);
            doc.AddAuthor("Jose");
            doc.AddTitle("Example");
            doc.Open();
            doc.Add(new Phrase("PDF example"));
            writer.Close();
            doc.Close();
            ms.Seek(0, SeekOrigin.Begin);
            var nameFile = string.Concat("reportName", ".pdf");
            return File(ms,"application/pdf",nameFile);
           
        }
```

The PDF file can be opened with web explorer, it's ok but when I save the file and try to open with Adobe Acrobat Reader, show an error dialog.
[image][image]
I need to add some instruction for compatibility?

Comment: _"when I save the file"_ - do you mean after you download it from the browser? Do you also have code that controls the download request?

Comment: **Don't close the `writer`!** Closing the `doc` will implicitly close the `writer` _after flushing some final data there_.